# React "Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### I want to write a small Audio Recording Website with ReactJS, but I alway get this error:

`Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'.`

#### Here's a part of the code I've written:

```
var [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);
var audiochunks = [];
var mrecorder;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then(stream => {

        mrecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mrecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {

            audiochunks.push(event.data);

        });

    })

function toggle_recording(){ setRecording(!recording); handle_record() }

function handle_record(){

        if(recording){
            mrecorder.stop();
        }
        else{
            mrecorder.start();
        }

    }

/**JSX Part of App.js component*/
return(

    <section>

         <button onclick=toggle_recording/>

    </section>

)
```

The buton toggles the recording state true or false and starts or stops the MediaRecorder.
Is it possible that the error comes up because I first declined the variable and initialized it in the getUserMedia function?
I hope you can hep me!
Thanks in advice,
Disembleergon

Comment: Your problem here is that you are trying to work outside the React render cycle. When you call `setRecording`, the component will rerender and all your data which is not contained within state will be lost. Here is a [simple voice recorder](https://codesandbox.io/s/audio-experiments-w7yz8?file=/src/App.js) I made in React when I started learning the Web Audio API, hopefully it will point you in the right direction - good luck!

Comment: Did you find the solution? If so, please post an answer

Comment: @EricNa no, I didn't find a solution and cancelled the project

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the `MediaRecorder` will throw an error when you try to stop the recording when the recorder is already in an inactive state. One thing you can do is to short circuit your stop action if mediaRecorder is already in an `inactive` state.

```js
const stopRecording = () => {
  if (mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') return
  mediaRecorder.stop()
}
```

By looking at your code, however, what I think could be the issue is that your `mrecorder` is a `var`. You should store it in `useState` so that when the re-render occurs on your component that your original `mrecorder` does not get wiped.