# InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'stop' on 'MediaRecorder': The MediaRecorder's state is 'inactive'

Tags: reactjs

```
const [rec, setRec] = useState({});
const [onRec, setOnRec] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(stream => {
        const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        setRec(mediaRecorder)
    })
}, [onRec]);
```

This is useEffect.

```
const onRecAudio = () => {
   
            rec.start()
            console.log(rec);
            console.log("start")
            setOnRec(false)
}
```

This is first click of function. recording start.

```
const offRecAudio = () => {
    rec.stop()
    console.log("stop")
    setOnRec(true)
}
```

This is second click of function. recording end.

```
<button onClick={onRec ? onRecAudio : offRecAudio } />
```

I don't want the useEffect to run those statements when the component is first rendered, but just click a button to run them. Press once to start recording, press again to end recording. But when I press it again, I see this error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720294/1066234

Answer (score 3):

I've come across the same error but with different patter, I didn't save MediaRecorder in state because I found it's hard to deal with complex objects and Web API interfaces when saving them and restore them from the state, so I used a react `ref` and two buttons for start and stop, the error was showing when I've forget to unbind the `stop` event listener, but after unbinding it, it works great.

I'll share my code with you and for the future people who want to record audio using react in a simple way:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
declare var MediaRecorder: any;


export function ChatsInputs() {

    const stopButtonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);


    function startRecording() {

        navigator
            .mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
            .then(function (stream) {
           
                const options = { mimeType: 'audio/webm' };
                const recordedChunks: any = [];
                const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function (e: any) {
                    if (e.data.size > 0) recordedChunks.push(e.data);
                });

                mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', function () {

                    setBlobUrl(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(recordedChunks)));

                });

                if (stopButtonRef && stopButtonRef.current)
                    stopButtonRef?.current?.addEventListener('click', function onStopClick() {
                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        this.removeEventListener('click', onStopClick)
                    });


                mediaRecorder.start();
            });

    }

    return (
        <div>
           
           
            <button onClick={startRecording}>{'rec'}</button>
           
            <button ref={stopButtonRef}>{'stop'}</button>
           
            <a download="file.wav" href={blobUrl}>{'download audio'}</a>
            {
                blobUrl ?
                    <audio id="player" src={blobUrl} controls></audio>
                    :
                    null
            }

        </div>
    );
}
```

[Ref Article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio)